# Can I use SqlCredential with Entity Framework for the SQL connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

I would like to use the secure SqlCredential object to handle credentials for connecting to our SQL database.

.NET has an overload of the SqlConnection constructor that takes a connection string and SqlCredential so you don't have to embed the credentials in the connection string itself. I would like to use something similar for Entity Framework when creating a DBContext instance.

1. I need to control the connection string that gets used by Entity Framework for the connection.
2. I would like to use the more secure way of handling credentials, using either SQLCredential, NetworkCredential, or SecureString and passing that to the DBContext to create the connection.

Is there any way to do this?

(As an aside, we can't use Windows integrated security as our database is not set up for that and I am not in a position to change that.)

Comment: Perhaps this could be of help: [Set credentials for Entity Framework in code, without using Integrated Security and only storing User ID in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6606020/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a regular SqlConnection with SqlCredential like you're used to and then pass this to the constructor of the entity framework DbContext.

The DbContext has this constructor:

```
public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection);
```